# Any Differences on defining classes having a parentheses within an object or not?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I am new to programming on Python and I have a doubt about defining a class. Will there be any differences the class has a parentheses within an object?

```
class MyFunction:
      def Method1(self):
          print('Hello World!')
```

or

```
class MyFunction(object):
      def Method1(self):
          print('Hello World!')
```

Thanks.

Comment: yes .... there is a difference the parentheses indicate the parent that the class will inherit from

Comment: See [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) in the Python tutorial.

Comment: By the way, it's a little confusing to call your class `MyFunction`. Occasionally you may want to write a class that's intended to be used as a callable (or even one that delegates to a `types.FunctionType`), but normally, classes and functions are pretty different things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) in the tutorial, this:

```
class DerivedClassName(BaseClassName):
```

… makes `DeriveClassName` inherit from `BaseClassName`.

You can inherit from 1 class, 2 classes, or 20 classes:

```
class Silly(Spam, Eggs, Cheese, Beans, Toast, Ham):
```

But you can't inherit from *no* classes. You *can* write a `class` statement with no base class names, but that means you're inheriting from the universal base class, `object`.

So, all three of these are identical:

```
class Derived: pass
class Derived(): pass
class Derived(object): pass
```

(However, this is only true for Python 3.0 and later. In 2.x, the first two actually create an "old-style" or "classic" class instead of a normal class.)

---

If you look at your class with `dir` or the `inspect` module, you'll see that it's got a whole bunch of things you didn't define anywhere—a `__repr__` method, a `__module__` string, and so on. A few of these are filled in automatically by the `class` statement, but most of them are inherited from `object.

Comment: Thanks for your words which make me clear on my concern.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses at the end of a [class declaration](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) indicate [it is inheriting from another class](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance). Example for Python 3.X.

Consider:

```
class OtherClass:
      def Method2(self):
          print("goodbye")

class MyClass1(OtherClass):
      def Method1(self):
          print('Hello World!')

class MyClass2():
      def Method1(self):
          print('Hello World!')
```

Then we can do:

```
> obj = MyClass1()
> obj.Method2
goodbye
```

But this will fail:

```
> obj = MyClass2()
> obj.Method2
AttributeError: MyClass2 instance has no attribute 'Method2'
```

Comment: with nothing it is implicitly inheriting from object (at least in py3)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and examples. I missed the concept of Inheritance here. Now, no doubt on this.